# SQL error an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'

Tags: java, sql

I have the below sql

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE CONCAT('%','CMP1','%') OR COLUMN LIKE 
CONCAT('%','CMP2','%')
```

I am replacing this programatically

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Items> getAllItems(String param);
```

I had to append these OR conditions based on the user inputs so the conditions varies hence I used it as a combined OR statements.

How do I resolve this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's say I call `getAllItems("Hello")`. That means you end up trying to run SQL: "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 'Hello'" which is invalid SQL for the exact reason stated: 'Hello' isn't a boolean. You can't put SQLese in that string (you can't call `getAllItems("column like CONCAT('%', 'CMP1', '%')")` - the point of these queries is that the SQL gets hardcoded and the dynamic data (the string param) is escaped.

You'd have to find a way to write this as a single SQL statement, or, don't use `@Query`.